# how to correctly get the value of an element by its index from TypedArray?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I use JavaScript and node. I need to read the raw bytes from the file.
I create a `Uint8array` and fill it with data from a file using `fs.Read`.
Then I output the data to the console of the array as a whole, and individual elements.
Instead of the values of the elements, I get zeros.
But it is clear that the array has non-zero data.

```
                    var buf1 = new Uint8Array( 4 );

                    fs.open( filePath, 'r+', function ( err, fd ) {
                        if (err) { console.error( err ) };

                        fs.read( fd, buf1, 0, buf1.length, 4,
                            function (err, bytes) {
                                if (err) { console.log(err) };

                        fs.close( fd, function (err) {
                            if (err) { console.log(err) };
                    }) }) });

                    console.log( buf1 );
                    console.log( buf1[0] );
                    console.log( buf1[1] );
                    console.log( buf1[2] );
                    console.log( buf1[3] );
```

[In the console, I see this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te1VP.jpg)

```
                    var buf2 = new Uint32Array( buf1.buffer );
                    console.log( buf2 );
                    console.log( buf2[0] );
```

[In the console, I see this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKghH.jpg)

Comment: TLDR; The `fs.*` functions are async. You print the content before you read the file. You also close the file before you finish reading it.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks, you're right. I have now started using `fs.ReadSync` and everything worked as I needed.